# UIScrollView scrolls randomly when adding content

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I've a view where some UITextViews are added to an UIScrollView. When the view appears, all data is loaded correctly to the scrollView but I've also a tableView where you can select diferent taxes for an item. Once you select an item on that tableView, the scrollView is cleared and mounted again with the new items. It fills the scrollView with the correct data but once it's filled, it scrolls randomly to any position of the scroll view instead of scrolling with no animation to the top. 
I've checked my code and after mounting the scrollView I use:

```
[self.scrollPreciosTarifasGUI scrollRectToVisible:CGRectZero animated:NO];
```

I've also tried to use:

```
[self.scrollPreciosTarifasGUI scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:NO];
```

But I've the same result.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had very similar issue with random scrolling and UITextViews. I really coudn´t find any solution but just by chance I placed one scrollview into another and it worked!

That´s my code:

```
//newDetailViewController.view is uiscrollview type
[self.mainScrollView addSubview:newDetailViewController.view];
[newDetailViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-2, 40, 800, 3300)];
```

Comment: So you mean to solve it by placing my scrollView into another scrollView?

Comment: That solved my problem. I added all data to a new scrollView created by code and once it's filled, I added it to the "main" scrollView. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution posted at http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/08/30/uiscrollview-setcontentoffset-random-scrolling-on-ios-4/ worked wonderfully for me.

> // Need to do this on iOS 4 or the view scrolls to random position
>   [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0,0)];
>
> // Update view with new content
>   [self updateContent:...]
>
> // We want the view to be on top every time it is shown
>   [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO];
>
> // And set the correct size to enable scrolling.
>   // contentHeight is updated when setting the content of subviews.
>   [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, contentheight)];

Comment: Adding an extra UIScrollView in the hierarchy did not work for me, but setting a zero content size before changing UITextView and then setting content size back, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this its just a wild guess

```
[self.scrollPreciosTarifasGUI scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,
                                                             0,
                                                             self.scrollPreciosTarifasGUI.frame.size.width,
                                                             self.scrollPreciosTarifasGUI.frame.size.height)
                              animated:NO];
```

Comment: Sorry but it's still not working. I've the same issue but thanks for answering!